# Etree is unable to pretty print

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

Why is `Etree` unable to pretty-print?

I ran the following program in `repl.it`:

**library.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library attrib1="att11" attrib2="att22">
    library-text
    <book isbn="1111111111">
        <title lang="en">T1 T1 T1 T1 T1</title>
        <date>2001</date>
        <author>A1 A1 A1 A1 A1</author>     
        <price>10.00</price>
    </book>
    <book isbn="2222222222">
        <title lang="en">T2 T2 T2 T2 T2</title>
        <date>2002</date>
        <author>A2 A2 A2 A2 A2</author>     
        <price>20.00</price>
    </book>
    <book isbn="3333333333">
        <title lang="en">T3 T3 T3 T3</title>
        <date>2003</date>
        <author>A3 A3 A3 A3 A3y</author>        
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
</library>
```

**main.py**

```
import lxml.etree as etree

dom = etree.parse("library.xml")    
xmlText = etree.tostring(dom, pretty_print=True)    
print(xmlText)
```

**Output**

```
b'<library attrib1="att11" attrib2="att22">\n\tlibrary-text\n\t<book isbn="1111111111">\n\t\t<title lang="en">T1 T1 T1 T1 T1</title>\n\t\t<date>2001</date>\n\t\t<author>A1 A1 A1 A1 A1</author>\t\t\n\t\t<price>10.00</price>\n\t</book>\n\t<book isbn="2222222222">\n\t\t<title lang="en">T2 T2 T2 T2 T2</title>\n\t\t<date>2002</date>\n\t\t<author>A2 A2 A2 A2 A2</author>\t\t\n\t\t<price>20.00</price>\n\t</book>\n\t<book isbn="3333333333">\n\t\t<title lang="en">T3 T3 T3 T3</title>\n\t\t<date>2003</date>\n\t\t<author>A3 A3 A3 A3 A3y</author>\t\t\n\t\t<price>30.00</price>\n\t</book>\n</library>\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `decode()` as in

```
print(xmlText.decode())
```

and see if it works.

Comment: why is `decode()` needed?

Comment: @user366312 The `b` in the `b'<library ...` in the beginning of your output indicates that the output is encoded; to pretty print it you need to reverse that, hence the `decode()`.